# Select the closest (selector) element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
<tbody id="tableBody">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="id" name="id" type="radio" value="1"></td>
        <td>Adam</td>
        <td>London</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="Radio1" name="id" type="radio" value="2"></td>
        <td>Steve</td>
        <td>New York</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="Radio2" name="id" type="radio" value="3"></td>
        <td>Jaques</td>
        <td>Paris, France</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input id="Radio3" name="id" type="radio" value="4" 
            checked="checked"></td>
        <td>Jora</td>
        <td>Chisinau</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

In a jQuery I selected the checked element (where the value = 4), like this:

```
var selectedRadio = $('#tableBody').find('input:radio:checked')
```

now I want to

```
selectedRadio.closest('tr').remove();
```

but before removing I want to check the previous (value = 3) radio...

How can I search the previous radio having the `selectedRadio` element, in order to check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $tr = selectedRadio.closest('tr')
$tr.prev().find('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', true)
$tr.remove();
```

Comment: the only problem here is if we have only one, the selected, <tr> )

Comment: works also with `find('input:radio:first').attr('checked', true)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedRadio = $('#tableBody').find('input:radio:checked');
var $tr = selectedRadio.closest('tr');
var $prev_tr = $tr.prev().find('input:radio');
$tr.remove()
```